# includes() not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer, methods, microsoft-edge

right here is a block of my code. It works perfect in fireFox and Chrome. But not in IE. I get the error "`Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'`"

```
function rightTreeSwapfunc2() {
    if ($(".right-tree").css("background-image").includes("stage1") == true) {
        $(".right-tree").css({
            backgroundImage: "url(/plant-breeding/img/scenes/plant-breeding/stage5.jpg)"
        })
    } else {
        $(".right-tree").css({
            backgroundImage: "url(/plant-breeding/img/scenes/plant-breeding/stage3.jpg)"
        })
    }
}
```

I could change it up a bit and use vanilla JS and do:

`document.getElementById("right-tree").classList.contains`

But I would rather see if there is a way to get it to work in IE before changing the JS and editing the HTML and CSS.

Comment: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) not stable function in cross browsers

Comment: includes is nothing to do with jQueery - the question is flawed :p

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using 1.x or 2.x? Also, I agree with Tushar - add the polyfill to your pages just incase other browsers do not support this feature.

Comment: The `.includes()` function has nothing to do with jQuery. `.css()` is a jQuery function and returns a string. `.includes()` is a function on the `string` object defined in ES6 which IE does not support. Your code is exactly the same as just doing `"foo".includes("o");` without jQuery.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), most of the browsers don't support this property.

You can use widely supported `indexOf()` after converting the property to string using `toString()`:

```
if ($(".right-tree").css("background-image").indexOf("stage1") > -1) {
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can also use the polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function() {
        'use strict';
        return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Had to swap out my instances of `.includes()` for IE compatibility. I changed `haystack.includes(needle)` to `haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1` and it works on IE11.

Comment: In case someone need it, you can use this directly with a string: if (SomeString.indexOf("SubString") > -1) { //Somecode }

Answer (score 11):

IE11 does implement String.prototype.includes so why not using the official  Polyfill?

Source: [polyfill source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
  if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
      if (typeof start !== 'number') {
        start = 0;
      }

      if (start + search.length > this.length) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: For Angular 2+ users: use import 'core-js/es7/array' which has the correct polyfill, import 'core-js/es6/array' doesn't have 'includes'

Answer (score 4):

In my case i found better to use "string.search".

```
var str = "Some very very very long string";
var n = str.search("very");
```

In case it would be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution ( ref : https://www.cluemediator.com/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-includes-in-ie )

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function (searchElement, fromIndex) {

      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      function sameValueZero(x, y) {
        return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
      }

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
          return true;
        }
        // c. Increase k by 1. 
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'core-js/es7/array'
```

into polyfill.ts worked for me.