# includes() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code. It works perfectly in browsers such as Chrome, Firefox or Edge. However when I check in IE11 it does not work and breaks all the functionality.

```
var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
if (href.includes('#')) {
  // action
}
```

I think `includes()` does not work in IE11. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is because `includes()` is unsupported in all versions of IE: [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#browser_compatibility)

Instead you can use the much more widely supported `indexOf()`:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if (href.indexOf('#') != -1) {
  // action
}
```

You could also prototype this to add the `includes()` method to IE:

```
String.prototype.includes = function(match) {
  return this.indexOf(match) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`includes` is not supported in Internet Explorer (or Opera)

Instead you can use `indexOf`. `#indexOf` returns the index of the first character of the substring if it is in the string, otherwise it returns -1. (Much like the Array equivalent)

Try the following:

```
var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

if(href.indexOf('#') > -1) //this will true if the string contains #
{
   // action
}
```

This is supported by all browsers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340868/includes-not-working-in-all-browsers) is a good read for your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can check. Because IE does not support includes: [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

You can use like this. Yes, I know this is VanillaJS way. If you work cross browser use this way to avoid errors.:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button')
var link = document.querySelector('a')
var isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Triden') > -1

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 
  var isHash = (!isIE) ? link.href.includes('#') : link.href.indexOf('#') > -1
  alert(isHash)
}, false)
```

```html
<button>Control hash</button>
<hr />

<a href="http://somesite.com/#/GetUsers">Users</a>
```