# Highcharts Drilldown no working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

This fiddle does not work in IE browser, been stuck for hours here.  Help me out with this. I have no idea why is it going wrong. the code works fine in Mozilla and in Chrome

[Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qrah67w/)

---

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        var chart = this;
        drilldowns = chart.userOptions.drilldown.series;
        series = [];
        e.preventDefault();
        Highcharts.each(drilldowns, function(p, i) {
          if (p.id.includes(e.point.drilldown)) {
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, p);
          }
        });
        chart.applyDrilldown();
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Scores par paliers'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      rotation: -45,
      align: 'right',
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
    },
    min: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Score'
    },
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    min: 0
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.point.drilldown) {
        var s = this.key + ' : <b>' + this.y + ' %</b>';
      } else {
        var s = this.key + ' : <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
      }
      return s;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Marches',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'september',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step1'
      },
      {
        name: 'october',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step2'
      }, {
        name: 'nov',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step3'
      },
      {
        name: 'dec',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step4'
      }, {
        name: 'jan',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step5'
      },
      {
        name: 'feb',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step6'
      },
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'spline',

    data: [{
        name: 'september',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step1'
      },
      {
        name: 'october',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step2'
      }, {
        name: 'nov',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step3'
      },
      {
        name: 'dec',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step4'
      }, {
        name: 'jan',
        y: 89,
        drilldown: 'step5'
      },
      {
        name: 'feb',
        y: 17,
        drilldown: 'step6'
      },
    ]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    drillUpButton: {
      relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
      position: {
        y: 0,
        x: -50
      }
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'step1',
        name: 'Step 1',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 100],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 100]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step2',
        name: 'Step 2',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step1',
        name: 'Step 1',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 83],
          ['Game 2', 82],
          ['Game 3', 79]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step2',
        name: 'Step 2',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step3',
        name: 'Step 3',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 100],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 100]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step4',
        name: 'Step 4',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step3',
        name: 'Step 3',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 83],
          ['Game 2', 82],
          ['Game 3', 79]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step4',
        name: 'Step 4',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step5',
        name: 'Step 5',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 100],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 100]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step6',
        name: 'Step 6',
        type: 'column',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step5',
        name: 'Step 5',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 83],
          ['Game 2', 82],
          ['Game 3', 79]
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'step6',
        name: 'Step 6',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
          ['Game 1', 0],
          ['Game 2', 100],
          ['Game 3', 0]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;">
</div>
```

Comment: which version of IE are you talking about and please update code you have tried in the question

Comment: IE 11and this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2qrah67w/

Comment: what error do you get in the console?

Comment: Since i m new to Stack overflow i didnt know how to add fiddle in my Question so bare with me.

Comment: the outer chart is working he inner drilldown is not happening

Comment: error in console?

Comment: the console gives no error the page loads fine but the drilldown is not happening at all

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbn8w68d/ these are the changes i made in the fiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340868/includes-not-working-in-all-browsers  you are using method includes which is not supported in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drilldown was not working in IE because you were using includes method which was not supported in IE. Using polyfill method for the method will make it work.

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
     String.prototype.includes = function() {
         'use strict';
         return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
     };
 }
```

Here is the updated [code](https://jsfiddle.net/user93/kabvss8p/) that works in IE.

Comment: Thanks mate , Works Fine but i dont know why we are adding the above script would be great if you could explain. New to Programming bare with me if it is a stupid question.

Comment: it is a polyfill. Since the string.prototype in IE does not has include method you are adding it manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5 hope it helps