# How to search through JSON and find every occurrence of a specific name (with increment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have a JSON data, that I want to automatically find every occurrence of a specific name.

```
{
  "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
  "servergenre2": "pop",
  "servergenre3": "rock",
  "servergenre4": "jazz",
  "servergenre5": "80s",
  "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
  "servertitle": "ServerHero",
  "bitrate": "48",
  "samplerate": "0"
}
```

in here `servergenre` is repeated a few times with increment (`2,3,4,5 and ...`)  as I do not know ho many `servergenre` there will be in the JSON, I need a method to loop through it and find as many times as there are instances of `servergenre` and add the result in an array possibly.

Something like this following code:

```
var URL = "http://name.com/file.json"
$.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
  var i = 1;
  $.each(data.servergenre + i, function(index, value) {
        /// CODE
  });
});
```

Obviously the code above does not work but that was my initial idea.

So any better idea to make it work and save all exisiting instances of `servergenre` in an array?

Thank is advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test each key of your JSON to see if it matches "servergenre". If it does, push the corresponding value to an array.

```js
let json = {
  "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
  "servergenre2": "pop",
  "servergenre3": "rock",
  "servergenre4": "jazz",
  "servergenre5": "80s",
  "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
  "servertitle": "ServerHero",
  "bitrate": "48",
  "samplerate": "0"
}

let result = []

Object.keys(json).forEach( key => {
  if(/servergenre/.test(key)) result.push(json[key])
})

console.log(result) // ["Classic Rock","pop", "rock","jazz","80s"]
```

Alternative method (inspired by osynligsebastian's answer) with filter and map :

```js
   let json = {
      "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
      "servergenre2": "pop",
      "servergenre3": "rock",
      "servergenre4": "jazz",
      "servergenre5": "80s",
      "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
      "servertitle": "ServerHero",
      "bitrate": "48",
      "samplerate": "0"
    }

    let result = Object.keys(json)
                    .filter( key => /servergenre/.test(key))
                    .map( key => json[key] )

    console.log(result) // ["Classic Rock","pop", "rock","jazz","80s"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will approve it. However, even though the code is working, in WebStorm editor is it picked as syntax error. I thought maybe you would know why. e.g. `error: expression expected for =>`  or `error: , expected for .test(key)){`

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Click on "Run code snippets" above, both snippets work.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597729/how-to-get-read-of-editors-error-for-object-key) as it is based on your answer on this post. Thanks

Comment: Sure did, and posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filter all keys containing the word "servergenre". See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/871f6vbt/1/)

```js
var data = {
  "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
  "servergenre2": "pop",
  "servergenre3": "rock",
  "servergenre4": "jazz",
  "servergenre5": "80s",
  "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
  "servertitle": "ServerHero",
  "bitrate": "48",
  "samplerate": "0"
}

let keys = Object.keys(data).filter(key => key.indexOf('servergenre') > -1);

console.log(keys);

keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
});
```

Comment: I like the filter approach.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps :**

1. get the array of the properties using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.
2. Use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on `Object.keys()` to filter out the elements from an array having same occurance(substring).
3. Use [string.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if a string includes "servergenre".
4. Use `Array.length` to get the counts of the element.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
  "servergenre2": "pop",
  "servergenre3": "rock",
  "servergenre4": "jazz",
  "servergenre5": "80s",
  "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
  "servertitle": "ServerHero",
  "bitrate": "48",
  "samplerate": "0"
};

var res = Object.keys(jsonObj).filter(item => { return item.includes("servergenre"); });

console.log(res.length);
```

Updated Answer as per the [Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) comment.In below demo, we are using `indexOf
()` instead of `includes()`.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "servergenre": "Classic Rock",
  "servergenre2": "pop",
  "servergenre3": "rock",
  "servergenre4": "jazz",
  "servergenre5": "80s",
  "serverurl": "http://www.name.com",
  "servertitle": "ServerHero",
  "bitrate": "48",
  "samplerate": "0"
};

var res = Object.keys(jsonObj).filter(item => { return item.indexOf("servergenre") != -1 });

console.log(res.length);
```

Comment: If this code is to be run in a browser, you'll have trouble with `string.includes`. Its support is still very poor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340868/includes-not-working-in-all-browsers

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for correcting me. I updated my answer please check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var URL = "http://name.com/file.json"
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
      for(var n in data)
      {
        if(n.substr(0,11)=="servergenre") alert(n);
      }
    });
```