# Filtering JSON by key

Tags: javascript, json, function

Is their a way where in I can filter the json by name and the child node names and construct a new output JSON.Since this is a long JSON I have it here

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/senthilthyagarajan/4fd48ebfff70c699ad90cea651b80f42/raw/cd06974c8dd96a5bd6a706ea8ed5f13a8e65f970/drill.json

From this above JSON I want to filter and construct the below JSON:

```
{
        "name": "Age",
        "code": "Age",
        "children": [{
                "name": "Female",
                "code": "Age_Female",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Female Â Â Under 5 years",
                    "code": "Q012027",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female Â 5 to 13 years",
                    "code": "Q012028",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 14 to 17 years",
                    "code": "Q012030",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 18 to 21 years",
                    "code": "Q012031",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Single Year",
                    "code": "FEMALE_SINGLE_YEAR",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female   Under 1 year",
                        "code": "Q012A27",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  1 year",
                        "code": "Q012B27",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  2 years",
                        "code": "Q012C27",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  3 years",
                        "code": "Q012D27",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  4 years",
                        "code": "Q012E27",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  5 years",
                        "code": "Q012A28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  6 years",
                        "code": "Q012B28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  7 years",
                        "code": "Q012C28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  8 years",
                        "code": "Q012D28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female  9 years",
                        "code": "Q012E28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 10 years",
                        "code": "Q012F28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 11 years",
                        "code": "Q012G28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 12 years",
                        "code": "Q012H28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 13 years",
                        "code": "Q012I28",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 14 years",
                        "code": "Q012A30",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 15 years",
                        "code": "Q012B30",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 16 years",
                        "code": "Q012C30",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 17 years",
                        "code": "Q012D30",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 18 years",
                        "code": "Q012A31",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 19 years",
                        "code": "Q012B31",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 20 years",
                        "code": "Q012C31",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Female Single Year Female 21 years",
                        "code": "Q012D31",
                        "count": 242
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 22 to 24 years",
                    "code": "Q012033",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 25 to 29 years",
                    "code": "Q012035",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 30 to 34 years",
                    "code": "Q012036",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 35 to 39 years",
                    "code": "Q012037",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 40 to 44 years",
                    "code": "Q012038",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 45 to 49 years",
                    "code": "Q012039",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 50 to 54 years",
                    "code": "Q012040",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 55 to 59 years",
                    "code": "Q012041",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 60 to 64 years",
                    "code": "Q012042",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 65 to 69 years",
                    "code": "Q012044",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 70 to 74 years",
                    "code": "Q012046",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 75 to 79 years",
                    "code": "Q012047",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 80 to 84 years",
                    "code": "Q012048",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 85 years plus",
                    "code": "Q012049",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female 18 years plus",
                    "code": "Q0120F_18P",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Aggregate Age Female",
                    "code": "Q013B_3",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female Average Age",
                    "code": "Q013B_3AV",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Female Median Age",
                    "code": "R013B_3MD",
                    "count": 242
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Male",
                "code": "Age_Male",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Aggregate Age Male",
                    "code": "Q013B_2",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male Â Â Under 5 years",
                    "code": "Q012003",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male Â 5 to 13 years",
                    "code": "Q012004",
                }, {
                    "count": 242
                    "name": "Single Year",
                    "code": "MALE_SINGLE_YEAR",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male   Under 1 year",
                        "code": "Q012A03",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  1 year",
                        "code": "Q012B03",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  2 years",
                        "code": "Q012C03",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  3 years",
                        "code": "Q012D03",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  4 years",
                        "code": "Q012E03",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  5 years",
                        "code": "Q012A04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  6 years",
                        "code": "Q012B04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  7 years",
                        "code": "Q012C04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  8 years",
                        "code": "Q012D04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male  9 years",
                        "code": "Q012E04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 10 years",
                        "code": "Q012F04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 11 years",
                        "code": "Q012G04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 12 years",
                        "code": "Q012H04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 13 years",
                        "code": "Q012I04",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 14 years",
                        "code": "Q012A06",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 15 years",
                        "code": "Q012B06",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 16 years",
                        "code": "Q012C06",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 17 years",
                        "code": "Q012D06",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 18 years",
                        "code": "Q012A07",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 19 years",
                        "code": "Q012B07",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 20 years",
                        "code": "Q012C07",
                        "count": 242
                    }, {
                        "name": "Male Single Year Male 21 years",
                        "code": "Q012D07",
                        "count": 242
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 14 to 17 years",
                    "code": "Q012006",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 18 to 21 years",
                    "code": "Q012007",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 18 years plus",
                    "code": "Q0120M_18P",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 22 to 24 years",
                    "code": "Q012009",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 25 to 29 years",
                    "code": "Q012011",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 30 to 34 years",
                    "code": "Q012012",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 35 to 39 years",
                    "code": "Q012013",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 40 to 44 years",
                    "code": "Q012014",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 45 to 49 years",
                    "code": "Q012015",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 50 to 54 years",
                    "code": "Q012016",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 55 to 59 years",
                    "code": "Q012017",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 60 to 64 years",
                    "code": "Q012018",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 65 to 69 years",
                    "code": "Q012020",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 70 to 74 years",
                    "code": "Q012022",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 75 to 79 years",
                    "code": "Q012023",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 80 to 84 years",
                    "code": "Q012024",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male 85 years plus",
                    "code": "Q012025",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male Average Age",
                    "code": "Q013B_2AV",
                    "count": 242
                }, {
                    "name": "Male Median Age",
                    "code": "Q013B_2MD",
                    "count": 242
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: You don't want `cake` in the new JSON?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the input you are working with and the corresponding desired output. And whatever attempt you have made on your own.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: I don't see any JSON? Looks like an array to me?

Comment: @NinaScholz I did modify the JSON and the desired output.Thank You.

Comment: and what do you want out of the given data?

Comment: @NinaScholz from the given input I want just the AGE node within which I would  filter male and female only discarding the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could now take the following:

```
result = data.children
    .filter(o => o.name === 'Age')
    .map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { children: o.children.filter(p => ['Female', 'Male'].includes(p.name)) }
    ));
```

Comment: `includes` is neat, but unfortunately [doesn't work in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340868/includes-not-working-in-all-browsers)

Comment: @SNT - I'd reccommen some light reading -> http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @NinaScholz I modifed my JSON and cant use your code to create a new JSON. If you could check this (https://jsfiddle.net/snt1/nLua0oob/13/) and also let me give a brief explanation for what the code does .So in case if my JSON changes I can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Sure

```
newJson = oldJson
           .filter( obj => ["Raised","Old Fashioned"].indexOf(obj.name) !== -1 )
           .map( obj => obj.topping )
```

This will give you an array of "topping" from the `raised` and `old fashioned` objects.