# Find all matches in string with regex in any order with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i find **all** matches below? The way i've got it now, it finds finds **any** match from the keywords array, but, since the word "not" is present, matches should be empty in the console.

```js
var title = "How to edit an image";
var keywords = ["image","edit","not"];
var matches = [];
if (title.search(new RegExp(keywords.join("|"),"i")) != -1) {
     matches.push(title);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Since the word "not" is present in the keywords, the output of the console should be blank, becuase "not" isn't in the title.

Comment: You can try something like this `keywords.every(word => title.includes(word))`. It will return `false` when all your words are not in `title`.

Comment: Is there a ie11 compatible version of that, i have to support that browser

Comment: You can use `indexOf()` for IE support

Comment: You can use `indexOf()` instead of `includes()` for IE.

Comment: So you're not looking for "all matches", you want to look for strings that contain all words in a list?

Comment: I'm looking for all the matches, so, since "not"  is present in the array, the console should be blank since that word is not in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the regex, just loop through the words using [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) , and check each keyword using <strike>[`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)</strike> (See below);

```js
console.log(Check("How to edit an image", ["image","edit","not"])); // false
console.log(Check("How to edit an image", ["image","edit"]));       // true

function Check(title, keywords) {
    return keywords.every(word => title.indexOf(word) > -1);
}
```

**Note**: Using [`title.indexOf(word) > -1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31340895/5625547) to support IE 11 as OP requested.

---

Edit; based on OP's comment;

<sub>Remove `"not"` from the `keywords` array to ensure the logic works</sub>

```js
var title = "How to edit an image";
var keywords = ["image","edit","not"];
var matches = [];
if (keywords.every(word => title.indexOf(word) > -1)) {
     matches.push(title);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate this into my logic, sort of struggling here, can you combine your code to my post above, with no arrow function

Comment: 0stone0, you are still using arrow functions!

Comment: I changed it a bit to remove that:

function findMatch(title, keywords) {
     return keywords.every(function(word) {
          return title.indexOf(word) > -1;
      })
}

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regex. Just map over keywords

```
const output= keywords.map(x=>
    title.indexOf(x)!==-1 ? title : ""
);

//output
["How to edit an image", "How to edit an image", ""]
```

Comment: How do i add this to my code above, with no arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order) as a reference, and olny if you are fixed to use Regex, you should use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*\bimage\b)(?=.*\bedit\b)(?=.*\bnot\b).*$
```

Applied on your Javascript code it would be something like:

```js
var title = "How to edit an image";
var title2 = "How to not edit an image";
var keywords = ["image","edit","not"];
var matches = [];

// Using for block because I don't remember if forof, forin or foreach are supported by IE 11
var regex = "^";
for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    regex += "(?=.*\\b" + keywords[i] + "\\b)"; // Needed beacuse template Strings are not supported by IE 11.
}
regex += ".*$"

if (title.search(new RegExp(regex,"i")) != -1) {
    matches.push(title);
}
console.log(matches);

if (title2.search(new RegExp(regex,"i")) != -1) {
    matches.push(title2);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: To say the true, @0stone0 answer is a lot better on terms of use. I posted this solution only if you really want to use regular expressions.